# Eclipse: is there a way to extract method at end of class?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, refactoring

Is there a way with Eclipse to change the "extract method..." refactoring default behaviour in order to put at end of the class the new method extracted ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem possible directly through an Eclipse option.

You would need to develop a specific plugin for that (similar to "[Triggering 'extract method' in Eclipse Refactoring/LTK API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17146038/6309)").

And you can have a look at Eclipse refactor resources listed in the [AutoRefactor project](https://github.com/JnRouvignac/AutoRefactor/issues/8):

- [JDT Extract method code](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/tree/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/core%20refactoring/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/code)
- [JDT Extract Method Tests](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/tree/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring/resources/ExtractMethodWorkSpace/ExtractMethodTests)
- "[Extract method revival](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Extract_method_revival)"